# Create a binary outcome with random forest

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
 TEAM1         TEAM2     EXPG1  EXPG2         Gewonnen    
 ADO Den Haag  Groningen 1.5950 1.2672        1
```

I now try to predict the column `Gewonnen` based on `EXPG1` and `EXPG2`. Therefore I created a training and test set and am creating the following model (all using `rcaret`):

```
modFit <- train(Gewonnen~ EXPG1 + EXPG2, data=training, method="rf", prox=TRUE)
```

I can't make a confusion matrix now because my data has more references. That's true because when I do:

```
pred <- predict(modFit, testing)
head(print)
```

It says:  `0.5324000 0.7237333 0.2811333 0.8231000 0.8299333 0.9792000`

Because I want to make a confusion matrix I can't turn them into on 0/1 but I have the feeling that there should be an option to do this in the model as well.

Any thoughts on what I should change in this model to create 0/1 values. I couldn't find it in the documentation:

```
modFit <- train(Gewonnen~ EXPG1 + EXPG2, data=training, method="rf", prox=TRUE)
```

Comment: What package are you using for random forests?  The answer to your question is that you need to run random forests in classification mode.  You are running it now in regression mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, as Tim Biegeleisen says, you should convert your `Gewonnen` variable to a factor (in both training & test sets), if it is not already:

```
training$Gewonnen <- as.factor(training$Gewonnen)
testing$Gewonnen <- as.factor(testing$Gewonnen)
```

After that, the `type` option in the `caret` function `predict` determines what type of response you get for a binary classification problem, i.e. class labels or probabilities. Here is a reproducible example from the [`caret` documentation](http://topepo.github.io/caret/training.html) using the `Sonar` dataset from the package `mlbench`:

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
str(Sonar$Class)
# Factor w/ 2 levels "M","R": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

set.seed(998)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = .75, list = FALSE)
training <- Sonar[ inTraining,]
testing  <- Sonar[-inTraining,]

modFit <- train(Class ~ ., data=training, method="rf", prox=TRUE)

pred <- predict(modFit, testing, type="prob") # for class probabilities
head(pred)
#        M     R
# 5  0.442 0.558
# 10 0.276 0.724
# 11 0.096 0.904
# 12 0.360 0.640
# 20 0.654 0.346
# 21 0.522 0.478

pred2 <- predict(modFit, testing, type="raw") # for class labels
head(pred2)
# [1] R R R R M M
# Levels: M R
```

For the confusion matrix, you will need class labels (i.e. `pred2` above):

```
confusionMatrix(pred2, testing$Class)
# Confusion Matrix and Statistics

#           Reference
# Prediction  M  R
#          M 25  6
#          R  2 18
```

Comment: I upvoted you because you gave the implementation details which I did not know offhand and could not find myself.  And you also acknowledged my answer in your own, which is rare these days on SO.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanx, that is what I always do! :-) Upvoted too, as I think your answer is essentially what was being asked for.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is a bit speculative as you omitted some critical details about your data set and I have not worked extensively with the `caret` package.  That being said, it appears that you are running random forests in *regression* mode, which means that you will end up with a continuous function.  This means that predictions can have a response value of `0`, `1`, or anything in between `0` and `1`.  If your `Gewonnen` column only has values of `0` or `1`, and you want predicted values to also behave this way, then you can try turning `Gewonnen` into a categorical variable.  As [this article discusses](http://bigcomputing.blogspot.sg/2014/10/an-example-of-using-random-forest-in.html), this might tell random forests to run in *classification* mode instead of regression mode.

```
Gewonnen <- as.factor(Gewonnen)
```

This builds the random forest as you did before, and you should have the responses you want.